# unable to install pip install thesaurus python 3.7.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, thesaurus

I am not able to install thesaurus library

```
C:\Users\veeransa>pip install thesaurus
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\program files\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
pip install py-thesaurus
```

Comment: This is working, But Using this library this code is not working

Comment: from thesaurus import Word
w = Word('box')
w.synonyms()
['carton', 'crate', 'pack', 'package', 'trunk', 'bin', 'case', 'casket', 'chest', 'coffer', 'portmanteau', 'receptacle']

Comment: Check this page: https://libraries.io/pypi/thesaurus. Maybe you will find the answer. Good luck!